# What is the meaning of following line of code in Golang?

Tags: go

```
var asciiSpace = [256]uint8{'\t': 1, '\n': 1, '\v': 1, '\f': 1, '\r': 1, ' ': 1}
```

how come we are allowed to have **:1** in the code above and what is the meaning of that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`asciiSpace` is declared an array of `uint8` with indexes 0 .. 255 (i.e. the ASCII range), and the values for the indexed elements are set to `1`.

The array indexes are given as `'\t'`, `'\n'` etc. indicating they refer to whitespace characters.

My guess is you misinterpreted the sequence "index **:** value".

A similar example is given in a (randomly chosen) [Go Tutorial](https://www.golangprograms.com/initialize-values-for-specific-array-elements-in-go.html).

Comment: ha, I've been programming with Go for years and didn't realize you could initialize and array like this. I suppose I don't use arrays all that often, and I'd usually use a map for something like this (unless I knew I was going to use most or all of the indices in the array).